# Generating new columns in an R dataframe based on applying a function across multiple columns

Tags: r, string, stringr

What I'd like to do is apply a function to multiple columns in a dataframe, recording the output as a new column.  To make this clearer, I'd like to take a dataframe of the form:

```
first_name  last_name   age
   Alice       Smith     45
    Bob       Richards   20
```

to:

```
first_name  last_name   age  first_name_lower  last_name_lower
   Alice       Smith     45      alice            smith
    Bob       Richards   20       bob            richards
```

I can do this column-wise with something like:

```
df$first_name_lower <- apply(df[,c('first_name')], 1, function(x) str_to_lower(x))
df$last_name_lower <- apply(df[,c('last_name')], 1, function(x) str_to_lower(x))
```

but of course for multiple columns this isn't a particularly elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to get a solution where all character columns get converted to lower case? Or you just need an alternate way of doing it in an elegant way?

Comment: Ideally all character columns get converted to lower case but are recorded as a new column and we preserve the original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work
`transmute_if` takes a predicate and performs and action on all columns satisfying the predicate and throws away all the rest - in this case we use `is.character as predicate`. Since we want to keep the orignial data we combine both datasets with cbind.
To change the names of the new columns we use `select_all` to paste `"_lower"` to end of the column names

```
dta <- read.table(header = TRUE,sep = ",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  text = "first_name,last_name,age
Alice,Smith,45
                  Bob,Richards,20")
library(tidyverse)
cbind(dta,
      dta %>%
        transmute_if(is.character,tolower) %>% 
        select_all(funs(paste0(.,"_lower")))))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are missing a comma after `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. With this the there would be multiple columns with same name in data.

Comment: @suchait your are right I added a fix to that problem renaming the new columns

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
    mutate(first_name_lower=first_name,
           last_name_lower=last_name) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars=first_name_lower,last_name_lower), ~ str_to_lower(.)))
```

Whether you don't want to preserve original variables:

```
mydf %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(first_name_lower, last_name_lower), ~ str_to_lower(.))
```

Comment: I like your approach, however, using column indices makes me nervous, wouldn't you consider `mutate_at(vars(first_name_lower, last_name_lower), ~str_to_lower(.))` an improvement?

Comment: Ok, but you have to use ""...in any case I consider it an elegant solution only if you don't have to change more than 3 o 4 variables ;-)

Comment: You can use bare column names using `vars()` as it supports unquoting. That makes `vars(colnames(df))` quite handy.